# Obfuscate Entity Framework ConnectionString with Base64

Tags: entity-framework, base64, connection-string, obfuscation

I use Entity Framework 6.0.0.0 (Code First) in my WCF Service. The ConnectionString in App.config is shown as plain text and I want to obfuscated it with Base64.
How can I do that?
Thanks.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Base64. That's security by obscurity. Use aspnet_regiis.exe to encrypt the connectionStrings section or do it with code as described here:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs

Comment: I know, but it is a requirement of the customers! He wants minimal protection and simple maintainability...

Comment: You should explain to the customer that this is bad practice and it should be encrypted properly. Anyone who will be able to make use of a connection string in plaintext would be able to figure out how to convert Base64